# difference between domain and directory installation in wordpress multisite

Tags: wordpress, multisite

What is the difference between multi domain and directory installation which we configure in wp-config.php before enabling multisite feature in wordpress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means exactly what it says.

- Domain: Creates a subdomain for every sub-site in your Wordpress installation. (eg. `site1.example.com`, `site2.example.com`, ...)
- Directory: Creates a directory for every sub-site in your installation. (eg. `example.com/site1`, `example.com/site2`, ...)

Take care if you choose `Domain` since it needs additional configuration in your DNS.

- Here are the [Docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network#Step_3:_Installing_a_Network) which explain them in detail.